# Handling error output of jpegtran when called with php system command

Tags: php, jpeg

```
    $cmd = 'jpegtran a.jpg > b.jpg';
    system($cmd);
    $newsize = filesize('b.jpg');
    if($newsize != 0) {
       copy('b.jpg','a.jpg');
    }
```

I want to run **jpegtran** on a bunch of images and copy the output to original file only if the command was successful.

When I run the above php code, for certain images I get errors like **'premature end of jpg file'** or **'empty input file'** etc.

How do I capture those errors and act accordingly in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how `jpegtran` returns on error but more usually the return code on error is something different than 0.

If so you could use `exec()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php instead of `system()` and get the result of `jpegtran` in the return_var like so:

```
exec('jpegtran a.jpg > b.jpg', $result, $return_var);

if( $return_var ) {
  // Error log here
}
```

Edit: I forgot `system()` returns return_var as well. So the same can be accomplished with `system('jpegtran a.jpg > b.jpg', $return_var);`